# Routing for components on same page in angular doesn't work

Tags: angular, routes, angular-components

I have a very common angular website design in which I have placed components in vertical way and wants to navigate through menu. For example, if I click on Contact link my focus should go to contact us component at the end of the page. But its not navigating.

```
<div fxLayout="column">
          <a mat-button routerLink="/aboutus">About</a>
          <a mat-button routerLink="/packages">Packages</a>
          <a mat-button routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
</div>

 <div class="compList">
             <app-about></app-about>
             <hr>
             <app-packages></app-packages>
             <hr>
             <app-outzone-package></app-outzone-package>
             <hr>
             <app-contact-us></app-contact-us> 
             <app-footer></app-footer> 
        </div>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is how I have placed my components in app.component.

I expect that when I click on any of the routerlink, it takes the focus to that component.

Without giving any error it doesn't move at all. I wonder if i need to make modules instead of components??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have app-routing.module.ts?
Did you import it in app.module.ts?  in your **app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about.component';
import { PackagesComponent } from './components/packages.component';
import { ContactUsComponent } from './components/contact-us.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
    {path: 'packages', component: PackagesComponent},
    {path: 'contact', component: ContactUsComponent},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and after import it in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate through routes with router link, you need to have that code inside a rotuer outlet and then lazyload your other components, those components has to be in a pages folder or components folder however you want to name it, inside that pages folder you need to have the same structure as your app folder like this:
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kqbi.png)

my app.component.html it's just a simple `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
and my routes in routes.ts  are something like this:

```
   const APPROUTES: Routes = [
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        {path: '',component: PagesComponent,
        loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'},
        { path: '**', component: NopagefoundComponent }
    ];
```

So instead these routes you should add your routes for: about, packages and outzone packages, and lazyload your PagesComponent.
In your pagescomponent.html you should put the code you are showing up in the question and it should work